# How can I take a screenshot in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: functionality

I need to take a screenshot of something on a Windows 8 phone, is there a key combination or app that can be installed that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Press the start and power buttons simultaneously. See [this article](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows-phone-8/windows-phone-8-tip-screenshots-144687) for details.

Some windows phones may use the Start and Picture buttons being pressed simultaneously instead of the Start and Power button.

Comment: There is a windows phone SE?  Dang nab it.

Comment: The power and start button open up a voice command for me.  Wound up being the Windows and Picture key though.  Accepting your answer as close enough.

Comment: @AngelBrighteyes , please consider editing the answer if it will make it more correct/useful.

Comment: The instructions as listed worked for me (HTC 8X).

Comment: Agree with Walter here - power & start works on a Lumia 920 too